# Find the file count and file name ignoring directories in the find command

Tags: linux, unix, find, command

I am looking for something like this

```
test1 : 2 
aaa.txt 
bbb.txt

test2 : 3 
ababa.txt 
cbbab.txt 
ddddd.txt

test3 : 1 
mmmm.txt
```

But my current code lists the directory as well. How do I remove the directories in the output

Here is my code

```
find /tmp/test/ -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read dir; do printf "%s : " "$dir"; find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l; find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f ; done;
```

What should I change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all outputlines will be caught in variables, so using the `${var##*/}` to remove the path from the var will not work. So just cut off the path of your complete output with sed:

```
find /tmp/test/ -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 1 -type d | 
   while read dir; do
      printf "%s : " "$dir"
      find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l
      find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f
   done | sed 's#.*/##'
```

When you want a nicer layout, you can use the construction:

```
find /tmp -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read dir; do 
   # Delete path from dir with ##*/
   printf "%s : " "${dir##*/}"
   find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l
   # Replace path with some spaces
   find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f | sed 's#.*/#   #'
   # Redirect the "permission denied messages" to the end of the Galaxy.
done 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the solution is found here: https://superuser.com/questions/620570/how-do-i-return-only-file-names-from-the-find-command

Try adding the `find . -type f -exec basename {} \;` command, to your first find query.

Comment: adding -exec basename doesnot quite work in my find statement

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$ find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} sh -c ' echo "{}: \c" ; find {} -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l ; find {} -maxdepth 1 -type f -print'
```

**UPDATE**

This one removes unwanted path...

```
$ find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} sh -c ' echo "{}: \c" ; find {} -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l ; find {} -maxdepth 1 -type f -print | sed "s#.*/##" '
```

Comment: This one also adds the part of directory in the filename, which I don't want